# Trying to stores the data in .as command but its returning Null when recalled using This.text

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to store a variable using .as command which stores the data but its returning Null when recalled using **This.text**

```
it('store variable',function(){

cy.log('ASDF').as('print')
}

it('print',function(){
cy.log(This.print)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `cy.log()` does not yield anything. Look at the docs, each command has a **Yields** section to let you know what gets passed to chained commands like `.as()`.

You want to use `cy.wrap()` instead.

```js
cy.wrap('ASDF').as('print')
```

Also don't use a capital `T` on `this`

```js
cy.log(this.print)
```

Comment: Thanks allot @Fody for the help, it worked.

Comment: I should note, as long as you use `function()` and `this.print` the alias value **will** be available in all tests in the same spec.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use the value saved in one `it` block to another. Aliases (`as`) won't be the right choice because cypress clears aliases between `it` blocks.

What you can use is the cypress environment variables to save your text, then you can use that text anywhere throughout your cypress project.

```js
it('store variable', function () {
  cy.get('selector')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
      Cypress.env('envVarText', text) //Saves the value
    })
})

it('print', function () {
  cy.log(Cypress.env('envVarText')) //gets the value
})
```

In case if you want to wrap the text, you can do this:

```js
it('store variable', function () {
  cy.wrap('ASDF').then((text) => {
    Cypress.env('envVarText', text) //Saves the value
  })
})

it('print', function () {
  cy.log(Cypress.env('envVarText')) //gets the value
})
```

Comment: Thanks @alapan-das , your code also worked and  as well as helped in clearing my concepts.